# Trait not found inside Laravel 5 unit tests

Tags: php, composer-php, phpunit, autoload

I'm writing some unit tests to test the API endpoints in my Laravel 5 application, and a lot of endpoints require user authentication. Instead of having the same user account creation code in every test, I wanted to define a `RegistersUsers` trait to use on the test classes, which will have a `registerUser()` method.

The directory structure of my `tests` directory is like so:

```
/tests
    /Traits
        RegistersUsers.php
    TestCase.php
    UserTest.php
```

I've namespaced `TestCase.php` and `UserTest.php` by adding this namespace declaration:

```
namespace MyappTests;
```

and I've namespaced `RegistersUsers.php` like so:

```
namespace MyappTests\Traits;
```

My `UserTest` looks like this, with the namespace and the `use` declaration so that I can leverage `RegistersUsers`.

```
<?php

namespace MyappTests;

use MyappTests\Traits\RegistersUsers;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    // ... rest of the class
```

However, when I run the test, PHPUnit dies with the fatal error:

> Trait 'MyappTests\Traits\RegistersUsers' not found in /home/vagrant/demo-app-net/tests/UserTest.php on line 9

As far as I can tell, my namespacing is correct and my trait should be found. I've been going around in circles with this and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm guessing having the trait in the traits folder, the trait is no longer accounted for in your autoloader.

In order to correct this, you should open up `composer.json`, find the sectionfor `autoload-dev` and change it to something like the following...

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php",
        "tests/Traits/"
    ]
},
```

And that should add any traits you have in that folder to the autloader.

**Edit**

Some additional ideas were brought up in the comments.  If you are going to be maintaining proper folder/namespace structure, it would be a good idea to use psr-4 autoloading rather than maintaining the class map.

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyappTests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

Also, rather than put logic in a trait to register a user for use with testing, when you extend `TestCase`, it brings in a helper method for logging in as a certain user.  You'd use it like so...

```
$user = User::find($id);
$this->be($user);
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem, I assumed it would just get automatically picked up! Thank you!

Comment: Or use psr4, which would find your Traits namespace.

Comment: Above change should help with the error, but IMO better solution would be to use Codeception to write tests instead of PHPUnit directly - it contains a lot of helper methods to make testing Laravel apps really easy. Including e.g. $I->amLoggedAs() method that will authenticate your user. See http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5 for more details.

Answer (score 15):

I'm developing a JSON REST API, and during tests development I found the need to refactor some of my testing functionalities inside a trait to be used inside test classes.

After renaming a class, PhpStorm wrote in the log something like:
`Fatal error: Trait 'controllers\ControllerTestWithUsers2' not found in ...`
when I tried to execute my test suite using the renamed trait.

The solution to my problem was to simply run the command `composer dump-autoload` and then try again to run my test suite.

I found that this operation has to be done every time a renaming is performed in PhpStorm.
It seems that the composer command regenerates some internal files pointing to the old class name, leading to the "Fatal error".